# String conversion with TEXT formula character limit?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to format a single number stored as a text value.

For example, I would like to convert:

5145350002005000080

To:

5145-350002-00500-0080

The formula I am using is:

=text(A1,"0000-000000-00000-0000")

The output I am receiving is:

5145-350002-00500-**0000**

Why are the last 4 characters "0000" instead of "0080" as I would expect?  Is there a character limit, or is my formula incorrect?

Comment: When I try to enter a value like "5145350002005000080" as a number in a cell, Excel converts it to 5145350002005000000. That number is 5-sextillion and some change. 

I suspect that is simply too large for Excel to interpret and I think it is being converted to scientific notation by default, which may cause the undesired rounding/truncation of the value.

Comment: @DavidZemens added possible solution to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [Large Number Arithmetic](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/misc_tutorials/project_euler/LargeNumberArithmetic.htm):

> The limit in Excel is 15 significant digits in a number. Enter a 16
>   digit credit card number and 1234567890123456 will become
>   1234567890123450.

Actually, even 514535000200500**1111** will result in `5145-350002-00500-0000`.

Moreover, take a look at formula bar when your input cell is selected - for my Excel 2007 I see:

[image: Excel number limit]

Hope that was helpful)

**EDITED:**

As a solution to solve the task - **keep your numbers formatted as text** and use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,6)&"-"&MID(A1,11,5)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

Comment: voted up for sound advice re: significant digits, but this does not solve the problem of how to convert the value to "5145-350002-00500-0080"

Comment: Thank you for the explanation/workaround, however, as I stated in the original question the value is stored as TEXT, not a number value.

Comment: @Addikt I'm not sure how function works, but perhaps it turns number-like string to number - and then all the above applies...

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a different mask I should be using rather than "0000-000000-00000-0000" which would produce the same output, but as a string, not a number.  I assume that "0" would evaluate to number-related formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom function. Place it in a regular code module of the workbook and you can call it in the cell by =FormatLargeNumber("A1")

```
Public Function FormatLargeNumber(val As String)
'This function parses extremely large numbers per your example.
' Modify as needed.
FormatLargeNumber = Left(val, 4) & "-" _
                    & Mid(val, 5, 6) & "-" & _
                    Mid(val, 11, 5) & "-" & _
                    Right(val, 4)



End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation/workaround, however, as I stated in the original question the value is stored as TEXT, not a number value.

Comment: The TEXT() formula is interpreting the value in that cell as a number, that is the source of the error.

The function I provide will convert (not merely "mask") the value as long as it is stored as a text/string.

Are you sure the values aren't numbers formatted as text, rather than true text strings?

Comment: They are true text strings.  The main reason I have not used number types is because I need to preserve leading zeroes.  Excel provides a "suggestion error" that the TEXT field may contain a number.  I figure that it's converting it to a number when I use the TEXT method.  Obviously, this is not the desired result.  I realize that I can use the function you provided, which I've already done (with the exception that I used a built-in function), but I would prefer not to.  My question is targeted at identifying whethere there is an easier way to do this using the TEXT function.

Comment: The goal is to to avoid complicated VBA/cell formulae when these formats need to change, and to determine if this is a case where Excel will never produce the desired result due to an inherent limitation.

Comment: OK I understand.  Without using the Left/Mid functions, or a VBA UDF to facilitate same, this is an inherent limitation. The TEXT formula receives a _numeric_ value and masks it. Because your string value **can** be interpreted as a number, the TEXT() formula appears to work (subject to the limitation of significant digits, described above).  But the TEXT formula cannot be applied to non-numeric strings. Try it out on a true text string like `=TEXT("ABCDEFG","000-000")` and you will see that the TEXT formula doesn't do anything. It only appears to work because your input string is numeric.