# Is there a character in Excel to mask a STRING using TEXT function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a character to mask STRING values within the Excel TEXT function?

Attempting to use a mask of `"0000-000000-00000-0000"` seems to convert a string to a number.  I simply want to add hyphens in between a specific number of characters.

I have also tried `"@@@@-@@@@@@-@@@@@-@@@@"` and `"####-######-#####-####"` but to no avail.

---

Background:

[In a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755672/string-conversion-with-text-formula-character-limit/14756265#comment20664893_14756265), it was determined that a particular custom number mask could not be applied to a string because of the 15 significant digit limitation in Excel.

The goal was to convert a TEXT value of `5145350002005000080` to `5145-350002-00500-0080` using the following formula:

```
=text(A1,"0000-000000-00000-0000")
```

The output produced was:

`5145-350002-00500-0000`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Excel string functions.

This works, though it is not the usual way of getting the job done:

```
  =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,16,0,"-"),11,0,"-"),5,0,"-")
```

The more typical method:

```
  =LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,6)&"-"&MID(A1,10,5)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair point, @Rachel. I've revised my response because my earlier answer was flawed due to a misreading of the question.

Comment: using REPLACE might not be the most common approach but it looks good to me - fewer function calls +1

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's impossible to apply markup to any **string** value using `TEXT` - as per [TEXT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) description, it may be done only for numbers:

> The TEXT function converts a **numeric value** to text and lets you
>   specify the display formatting by using special format strings.
>
> Syntax
>
> `TEXT(value, format_text)`
>
> The TEXT function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> `value`    Required. A **numeric value**, a formula that evaluates to a numeric value, or a reference to a cell containing a numeric value.

So it looks like the only way for you to achieve what you want - is to apply recommended string conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells->Press Ctrl+1->from Number Tab of Format Cells Dialog select "custom"  and paste in Type edit box Below.

"Boxes";"Boxes";"Boxes";"Boxes"

[image]

Source: [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5494bd09-564f-4b0b-80ab-c877ca3f9dc4/mask-values-as-text-show-text-in-place-of-values-while-keeping-the-values?forum=excel)